# Export a backup from a container to host machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, cp

I have a docker container running mongoDB and want to export the database to my local file system.

I have created a mongo dump by running

```
mongodump -u root -p root -o /data/my_dump
```

Which has created the dump inside of my container - Now i want to bring this folder to my host machine.

I have tried running:

```
docker cp . mycontainerID:/data/mydump
```

but nothing really seems to be happening, It will take some time and then show an x on the terminal without telling me if there was an error or not or what went wrong.

Does anyone know what im doing wrong here?
I am trying to copy the file to wherever i run the command in the terminal

Comment: Please review the documentation for [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/). The command line you are using is trying to copy a local file named `.` into the container as `/data/mydump`.

Comment: To add, try using `docker cp mycontainerID:/data/mydump .`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to do this? I guess it's the best way to keep data.